# How to change my fragment's text by menuitem click

Tags: java, android

MainActivity.java code for MenuItemClick:

```
 mtoolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

               case R.id.readatnight:
                      //how to write
             }
```

ViewPagerAdapter class in MainActivity.java:

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int positions) {
        return super.getItemId(positions);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int positions){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (positions) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new fragment0();
                break;
        }
        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return 1;}
}
```

My fragment0.java:

```
  public class fragment0 extends Fragment {
TextView mtxts;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.testss, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mtxts = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txts);
    mtxts.setText(R.string.A0101);
 }
}
```

My menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/readatnight"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/moonc"
    android:title="夜讀模式"/>
</menu>
```

My question is how to write menuitemclick event so that change my fragment's text size, background color, and text color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your `Fragment0` class (classes should always begin with a Capital letter), you'll need to create a setter method where you can set your `TextView`'s content:

```
public void setText(String text) {
    mtxts.setText(text);
}
```

In your `MainActivity`, grab the instance of your fragment and cast it to `Fragment0`. In your case this should be safe as index 0 will always return an instance of `Fragment0`, this assumes that your `SectionsPagerAdapter` is called `mFragmentAgapter`

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.readatnight:
        Fragment0 fragment = (Fragment0) mFragmentAdapter.getItem(0);
        fragment.setText("Hello world, 晚安!");
        break;
}
```

And add other setter methods in your `Fragment0` for text colour etc.

One thing to keep in mind though, you're always creating a new instance of a fragment every time `getItem(int)` is called. Instead you should keep a reference to your fragment and only create a new instance if that reference is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.training1_fragment, container, 
              false);

       setHasOptionMenu(true);

       return v;
 }

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_save : 
       {
       //Write here what to do you on click
        return true;
     }
   }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```